# unresolved externals error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am testing a lib and got error unresolved externals. I did A/B test on two classes, `TestBufferPrint` and `TestMathLib`, both has a simple static function. I call them from Main.cpp in another project but only one of them works, and another is unresolved externals error:

```
*error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl pClickDLL::TestBufferPrint::Print(int)" (?Print@TestBufferPrint@pClickDLL@@SAXH@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl UnitTests::FeatureDerivationTests::Test(void)" (?Test@FeatureDerivationTests@UnitTests@@SAXXZ)   PClickDll\UnitTests\UnitTests.obj*
```

I suspect it results from header files inclusion: **CommonLibrary.h is included by many other files but TestMathLib.h is included only by Main.cpp and TestMathLib.cpp**. But I am not sure and do not get why header files inclusion could make errors.

Main.cpp

```
pClickDLL::TestMathLib::Print(123);   // works fine
pClickDLL::TestBufferPrint::Print(123);  // unresolved externals
```

TestBufferPrint  and TestMathLib classes:

CommonLibrary.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

namespace pClickDLL
{
class TestBufferPrint
    {
    public:
        static void Print(int a);
    };
}
```

CommonLibrary.cpp:

```
#include "../inc/CommonLibrary.h"

namespace pClickDLL
{
    void TestBufferPrint::Print(int a)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

TestMathLib.cpp

```
#include "TestMathLib.h"
#include <iostream>
namespace pClickDLL
{
    void TestMathLib::Print(int x)
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
}
```

TestMathLib.h:

```
#pragma once
namespace pClickDLL
{
    class TestMathLib
    {
    public:
        static void Print(int x);
    };
}
```

**UPDATED**:

This issue is solved, please check discussion below. The problem is **Visual Studio does not compile every files under project folder**. You want to check the output log to make sure every file is compiled.

Comment: Which is exactly the error message?

Comment: @DGomez please check my updated text.

Comment: @anthony-arnold what's the reason?

Comment: Are you compiling the .cpp file which includes that method?? is a linker error, so perhaps you're not compiling that file

Comment: Make sure that 1) you actually link with the object file or library that results from compiling `CommonLibrary.cpp`, and 2) you have recompiled that file since you introduced or modified the function. In particular 2) is a common problem: You modify code but forget to recompile, so the other parts of the project still link against an old version.

Comment: @DGomez yes I think so, because it works when I moved TestBufferPrint::Print() definition to the header file. But I don't know why Main.cpp can't find the definition.

Comment: @jogojapan you are right. I checked the output log in VS, and CommonLibrary.cpp is missing. Then I remove CommonLibrary.h and CommonLibrary.cpp and add them into project again. And it works out. It's really weird why VS did not compile the files already under project folder.

Comment: Best self-answer your question and put the description of what you did in the answer. This question is very localized as well as similar to others, but it may still be useful for somebody in the future.